Finding all positive reals $r$ satisfying $y_1=\frac{N}{2(1+r)}$ and $y_2=\frac{N}{2(1+1/r)}$ for positive integers $y_1$, $y_2$, $N$
$y_1$, $y_2$ and $N$ are all positive integers. Given you know the value of $N$, find all the positive values of $r$ ($ r\in \mathbb{R^+})$ that satisfy the following two equations.
\begin{equation}
y_1 = \frac{N}{2(1+r)}\\
y_2 = \frac{N}{2(1+1/r)}\\
\end{equation}

Ah thanks, I can change my title then. Do you think "Simultaneous with integer constraints" is better?

Eliminating $N$ yields $,r = y_2/y_1.\ $ Surely a duplicate. $\ \ $

All this shows is that $r$ must be a rational number, but it doesn't solve the original problem because if you rearrange both equations you get another form: Eqn1 $r = y_2/y_1$ and Eqn2 $N=2(y_1+y_2)$. If I choose $r$ to be any rational number then it might not satisfy Eqn2.

If $,r = a/b,$ in least terms then your equations are equivalent to  $,2(a+b)\mid N.\ \ $

I agree! I think you helped me solve it. I just found out that as long as N is even then all integer solutions will solve Eqn2: $y_1 = 1,2,3,...(N/2)-1$ and $y_2 = (N/2)-1, (N/2)-2,... 2,1$. This means there will be $(N/2)-1$ unique solutions for $r$ and each will be given by $r = y_2/y_1$

The two equations can be rewritten as:
$$r = \frac{y_2}{y_1}$$
$$N = 2(y_1 + y_2)$$
If $N$ is even then all integer solutions will solve the second equation up to $(N/2)-1$. In other words: $y_1 = 1,2,3,...(N/2)-1$ and $y_2 = (N/2)-1, (N/2)-2,... 2,1$.
This means there will be $(N/2)-1$ unique solutions for $r$ and each solution of $r$ will be given by $r = \frac{y_2}{y_1}$.
If $N$ is odd then there are no solutions for $r$
